# Trying to convert a while loop into a basic loop in Pl/SQL

Tags: loops, plsql

> this is what i have so far.

**Expected Result**:

```
1+1 = 2 1+2 = 3 1+3 = 4 1+4 = 5 then 
2+1 = 3 2+2 = 4 so on until 4+4 = 8*
```

---

**Code I've Tried:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    v_i number := 1;
    v_j number := 1;
    v_x number := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE v_i < 5 LOOP
        WHILE v_j < 5 LOOP
             v_x := v_i + v_j;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_i||'+'||v_j||' is: '||v_x);
             v_j := v_j +1;
        END LOOP;
        v_i := v_i + 1;
        v_j := 1;
    END LOOP;
    END;
    /
    SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

solved it. thanks

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
v_i number := 1;
v_j number := 1;
v_x number := 0;
BEGIN
LOOP
v_x := v_i + v_j;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_i||'+'||v_j||' is: '||v_x);
v_j := v_j + 1;
IF v_j = 5 THEN
v_j := 1;
v_i := v_i + 1;
EXIT WHEN v_i = 5;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

it was a simple logic mistake

Comment: What is the output you currently get ?

Comment: For the while loop is

Comment: SQL> @LOOP0
1+1 is: 2
1+2 is: 3
1+3 is: 4
1+4 is: 5
2+1 is: 3
2+2 is: 4
2+3 is: 5
2+4 is: 6
3+1 is: 4
3+2 is: 5
3+3 is: 6
3+4 is: 7
4+1 is: 5
4+2 is: 6
4+3 is: 7
4+4 is: 8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: now i cant get the syntax changed into a basic loop

Comment: this is jumping out of the loop when i need to increment v_j.  Don't you mean v_i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PI/SQL, but from what I understand this might do what you want. I used indentation for clarity, remove it if it's not allowed in PI/SQL

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
v_i number := 1;
v_j number := 1;
v_x number := 0;
BEGIN
LOOP
   v_x := v_i + v_j;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_i||'+'||v_j||' is: '||v_x);
   v_j := v_j + 1;
   IF v_j = 5 THEN
      IF v_i < 4 THEN
        v_i := v_i + 1;
        v_j := 1; 
      ELSE   
        EXIT;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```